# Relation of Sets on a real world example

Tags: relations, problem-solving

Let A be the set of people, and P, F, M, S, B the relations over A of ‘parent of’, ‘father of’, ‘mother of’, ‘sister of’ and ‘brother of’, respectively. 
Describe the SºP relation in real world?

Solution in the book.

SºP D ‘parent of a sister of’. Reason: a is a parent of a sister of c iff there is an x such that a is a parent of x and x is a sister of c.

My logic.

If aSb then a is the sister of b. If cPd then c is the parent of d.|=>
uSºPv would mean that there exists "x" such that uSxPv, which in turn would mean that "u" is the sister of "x" and "x" is the parent of v. 
So if we draw this. It would look like this.

```
u-----x
      |
      |
      |
      v
```

So the relation of u to v is "sibling's child". (We don't know if x is a man or woman).

I would appreciate if someone could explain the solution and show the fallacy in my logic.

Comment: Looks to me that your book has a typo. $S\circ P$ should be "sister of parent of," i.e., one of the input's aunts.

Comment: @mrob Some people define the composition $A\circ B$ of two relations to be $\{(x,y):(\exists z)\,(xAz\text{ and }zBy\}$ and others define it as $\{(x,y):(\exists z)\,(xBz\text{ and }zAy\}$. One definition will produce "sister of parent" in this example and the other definition will produce "parent of sister." Without knowing how the book used by the OP defines composition, there's no way to decide between the two.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If someone is interested, the example is from the book written by David Mackinson, "Sets Logic and Maths for Computing" page 40.